# My Schengen application is rejected 1 week before my travel, can I appeal with new dates?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, austria, itineraries, visa-refusal-appeal

- I submitted a visa application to travel between **13-17** of September
- My visa rejection respond was issued on 5th of September (with 2 weeks to appeal) meaning that I can appeal till 19th of September
- If I submitted the appeal on 16th of September (knowing that my orignal request was 13-17, can I add new dates to the documents that I have?)

Comment: Do you actually have a really good reason to appeal the decision? Appealing only makes sense if they clearly messed up while your application was bulletproof. If there's anything you could have done better, just submit a fresh application.

Comment: Of course the new dates must be consistent with the stated goal of your visit. If you intended to go to a conference for instance, you can’t switch to another conference just to (try to) get a visa.